# variable in data property are updated to unexpected value in Vue.js2.6

Tags: vue.js

I have two input tags for uploading images and tow variables(imgFile1,imgFile2) in data section . I'm sure imgFile1 gets correct value on my console but when I upload second image, this images's value goes to wrong variable. The images d57f0.... in the picture below supposes to be in imgFile2. Why does it happen ?? Thank you so much .[image]

```
html

         <div class="img-field-container1">
            upload img
            <input type="file" class="input-img-field1" @change="uploadFile" accept="image/*" ref="img1">
          </div>
          <div class="img-field-container2">
            upload img
            <input type="file" class="input-img-field2" @change="uploadFile" accept="image/*" ref="img2">
          </div>
```

```
data () {
    return {
      imgFile1:'',
      imgFile2:'',
    }
```

```
methods: {
   uploadFile: function () {
      var img_file1 = this.$refs.img1.files[0]
      this.imgFile1 = URL.createObjectURL(img_file1)
      console.log(imgFile1)→ correct value in console
      var img_file2 = this.$refs.img2.files[0]
      this.imgFile2 = URL.createObjectURL(img_file2) 
      console.log(imgFile2)→ correct value in console but updated into imgFile1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem by  wrapping  correctly